# jQuery how to load multiple page parts via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

My page shows multiple tables for different categories, each table is loaded via ajax.

The number of categories may vary, but I know how many there will exist before making the ajax calls. And I show them all at the same time like so:

```
$(function(){
    var categories = 3; // this is calculated dynamically
    var categoriesLoaded = 0;

    $('#categoryA').load('/getCategoryA', function(){categoriesLoaded++;checkLoadProgress();});
    $('#categoryB').load('/getCategoryB', function(){categoriesLoaded++;checkLoadProgress();});
    $('#categoryC').load('/getCategoryC', function(){categoriesLoaded++;checkLoadProgress();});

    function checkLoadProgress(){
        if(categoriesLoaded == categories){
            $('.spinner').hide();
            $('.categories').show();
        }
    }
});
```

This works and all but I wanted to know from you if this is a decent way of accomplishing this.

My goal is to have a loading bar (maybe I already have enough information for that) but I really don't like the way I'm checking the status, with that repetitive function. Any tips are welcome

Comment: Why are you using Ajax? What is the server used for?

Comment: Ever thought of having an array of the categories then loop through it?

Comment: @JustinGingyMcDonald I'm using ajax because the tables can take quite some time to load and the user can perform other actions while they are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make some changes (but generally i think your code is not bad):

```
$(function(){
    var categories = 3; // this is calculated dynamically

    for(var categoriesLoaded = 0; categoriesLoaded < categories; categoriesLoaded++){
        var charCode = String.charCodeAt('A') + categoriesLoaded;
        var symbol= String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        $('#category'+ symbol).load('/getCategory' + symbol, function(){categoriesLoaded + 1;checkLoadProgress();});
    }

    function checkLoadProgress(){
        if(categoriesLoaded == categories){
            $('.spinner').hide();
            $('.categories').show();
        }
    }
});
```

BUT! You use checkLoadProgress() only when all categories loaded and it returns nothing, that's why it seems like you can just write:

```
$(function(){
    var categories = 3; // this is calculated dynamically

    for(var categoriesLoaded = 0; categoriesLoaded < categories; categoriesLoaded++){
        var charCode = String.charCodeAt('A') + categoriesLoaded;
        var symbol = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        $('#category'+ symbol).load('/getCategory' + symbol);
        //function() was deleted
    }

    $('.spinner').hide();
    $('.categories').show();
});
```